# DTW kernel error rate at 0.8 with Multiclass SVM

Tags: c#, machine-learning, svm, accord.net

DTW kernel gives me a high error rate of 0.8 for my data, whereas HMM on the same data provides me with 95% accuracy. So, my data is not redundant. I am trying to classify different gestures and my data set comprises of vectors of histogram from images. My data set has 4 different classes, varying length of sequences and 16 feature vectors. In total, i have 110 sequences. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887010/svm-with-dynamic-time-warping-kernel-return-error-rate-greater-than-0) which suggests to use sequential minimal optimization along with Multiclass SVM. To test, i used something like this:

```
double[][][] trainArray = train.ToArray();
int[] labelArray = labels.ToArray();

var gkernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(length: 16);

svm = new MulticlassSupportVectorMachine<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>(0, gkernel, 4);

        // Create the Sequential Minimal Optimization learning algorithm
     var smo = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
        {
            Learner = (param) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
            {
                Kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(16),
            }
        };

        smo.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;

     // And use it to learn a machine!
        svm = smo.Learn(trainArray, labelArray);

        int[] predicted = svm.Decide(trainArray);
        double[] scores = svm.Score(trainArray);
        double error = new ZeroOneLoss(labelArray).Loss(predicted);
```

Apart from this, Gaussian kernel was also suggested to improve the results further but i am not pretty sure how do i use it to learn SMO with SVM. Moreover, the suggested method works for binary classes but not sure about multiclass where i need class labels as output as integers and not boolean.

I used 4-fold cross validation of 80% and 20% and the results look like this:
[image: results]

I would appreciate suggestions to improve my test results.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the data you are using in your example? You can open an issue in Accord.NET's issue tracker and upload it there.